# How to setup DNS manually on Linux?

Tags: debian, networking, dns, vpn, resolv.conf

In Linux `/etc/resolv.conf` get often overwritten when we setup the DNS, because of the multitude of programs managing the DNS servers.

How to properly setup the DNS ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## DNS Config Under Linux

**DNS usage on linux is done over** a set of routines in the C library that provide access to the Internet Domain Name System (DNS). The resolver configuration file (`resolv.conf`) contains information that is read by the resolver routines the first time they are invoked by a process. In short each process requesting DNS will read `/etc/resolv.conf` over library. **The NSS** is layered on top of this, and is configured by `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.

**Linux DNS config** are located in the file `/etc/resolv.conf` **BUT** there are a number of programs/services that wants to automatically manage and handle the DNS configuration file at `/etc/resolv.conf`. In some situations you may want to manage this file yourself. Each program/service managing DNS have its own configuration files like `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` (for dnsmasq service) and append the DNS config at connection change and/or on other events... a quick solution is to lock the DNS config file with `chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf` but this is not recommended in certain case, a better solution is to setup correctly all the program/services using the DNS like (dnsmasq/network-manager/resolvconf/etc.)

## Getting Back The Control Of DNS

Here is an exhaustive list of setups **to get back the control of resolv.conf** and avoid having it overwritten (**how to disable/setup DNS from other location other than resolv.conf**) note that resolvconf is an independent program from resolv.conf, also depending on your system/config you may not have one or many of the programs listed here.

#### 1. Resolvconf:

*Config files*

```
cat /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head
nameserver 8.8.4.4
cat /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

*Update the config*

```
sudo resolvconf -u
```

*Disable resolvconf*

```
systemctl disable --now resolvconf.service
```

#### 2. Dnsmasq Service:

*Config files*

```
cat /etc/dnsmasq.conf
server=1.1.1.1
server=8.8.4.4
```

*Update the config*

```
sudo systemctl restart dnsmasq.service
```

#### 3. Network Manager:

*Config files*

```
/etc/NetworkManager/*
```

*Disable DNS*

```
$ cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-dns.conf
[main]
dns=none
```

*Enable DNS*

```
$ cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/dns.conf
[main]
dns=default

[global-dns]
searches=example.com

[global-dns-domain-*]
```

*Use resolved service*

```
$ cat /usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/resolved.conf 
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved
```

*Use resolvconf*

```
$ cat /usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/resolvconf.conf 
[main]
rc-manager=resolvconf
```

*Update the config*

```
systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
```

#### 4. Network Interfaces:

*Config files*

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
#nameservers
# or dns-search like so
# dns-search x.y 
dns-nameservers 4.4.4.4 8.8.8.8
```

*Update The Config*

```
reboot
```

#### 5. DHCP Client:

*Config files*

```
$ cat /etc/dhcp3/dhclient.conf
supersede domain-name-servers <dns_ip_address1>,<dns_ip_address2>;
```

*Update The Config*

```
reboot
```

#### 6. Rdnssd Service:

*Disable rdnssd*

```
systemctl disable --now rdnssd.service
```

#### 7. Resolved Service:

*Disable resolved*

```
systemctl disable --now systemd-resolved.service
```

#### 8. Netconfig:

*Config files*

```
/etc/sysconfig/network/config
```

*Disable netconfig*

```
cat /etc/sysconfig/network/config
NETCONFIG_DNS_POLICY=""
```

*Update The Config*

```
reboot
```

## Setting The DNS Server

Example of a `/etc/resolv.conf` configuration

```
#Cloudflare
nameserver 1.0.0.1

#Google
#nameserver 8.8.8.8
#nameserver 8.8.4.4

#Cloudflare 
#nameserver 1.1.1.1

#Classic Config
#nameserver 192.168.1.1
#search lan
```

Comment: The name resolving functions (like `getaddrinfo`) in the C library is the interface to the DNS. The rest is just an implementation detail. The file `/etc/resolve.conf` is commonly used for configuring lookups, but not necessarily: a system using `systemd-networkd` and `systemd-resolved` can function perfectly well without `/etc/resolve.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

On Fedora 36 I did:

```
# print existing DNS settings for all interfaces
$ resolvectl dns

# set new DNS
$ resolvectl dns enp0s22f6 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

# check again
$ resolvectl dns
```